ktfmt shortcut in IntelliJ Idea Keymap?
My ktfmt shortcut for code formatting in IntelliJ Idea (command + shift + L) stopped to work, re-installing plugin and invalidating caches doesn't help.
I tried to find its key binding in Settings -> Keymap, but haven't found any. There is no "ktfmt" section in "Plugins", and searching for "formatting" "ktfmt", etc is useless.
What is the name for ktfmt shortcut in Keymap?
